# navegacion a una propiedad epecifica

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy realizando una API , la cosa es que quiero listar los datos de una tabla "businessobject" que tiene relacion con otras tablas.Estoy usando DTO para no enviar todo los datos de la tabla sino las que se requieras,el detalle es cuando quiero navegar a datos mas "profundos" de una relacion. es como si no le reconociera.
CODIGO.

```
 public function  all()
{
    $listClassBo = $this->model->with(["promotionproduct.promotion", "categorybusinessobject.category", "businessobjectrole"])->where("state", 1)->get()->map(function ($businessobject) {
        return ClassBo::fromRepositoryToBo(ClassRepositoryDto::fromModelToRepository($businessobject));
    });
           return $listClassBo;
}
```

Y mi DTO de "ClassRepository" que devuelve un objeto con informacion necesaria, lo tengo asi:

```
  public static function fromModelToRepository(Businessobject $businessObject): self
{
    $properties = [
        "id" => $businessObject->id,
        "name" => $businessObject->name,
        "type" => $businessObject->type,
        "category" => $businessObject->category_business_object,
        "price" => $businessObject->price,
        "state" => $businessObject->state,
        "promotion" => $businessObject->type == TypeClassEnum::especial() ? $businessObject->promotion_product : null,
        "role" => $businessObject->businessobjectrole
    ];
    return new self($properties);
}
```

ya hice varias pruebas y en la lista me sale null la promocion y las categoria, es por que no puedo acceder a esos valores,alguna forma de hacerlo?
resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos las relaciones que tienes en cada modelo? Cómo se llaman los métodos? Porque en la relación las llamas `categorybusinessobject` pero dentro de tu DTO los llamas así `category_business_object`

Comment: si eso era amigo , es que en el JSON que muestra el resultado ,me mostraba una propiedad promotion_product, por eso pensé que se creaba con ese nombre, solo era acceder promotionproduct.